# Share on Facebook/LinkedIn in private message not available on mobile, but it's available on a computer

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api

I have a share link on my website that looks like this for facebook : [Facebook Share Link](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.google.com/) and this for linkedin : [LinkedIn Share Link](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.google.com/).

When I click it to share my page on a computer, it gives me the option to share in private message to a friend. However the option is not there when I try on a mobile device (iphone, android). Am I doing something wrong or are the APIs not allowing this ?